# How to verify JSON result of smart contract method call on my own backend?

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, nft, signature, smart-contract-wallets

I am developing the dApp (related to ERC-721 based NFT) which works with my own backend.

I am going to send the result JSON for a smart contract method call to my own backend.

On my backend I want to verify this result JSON data. That's I need to make sure that this result JSON is correct and not fake data.

How can I get this done? Shall I use etherscan API using blockhash and sender's address?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not clear to me. Can I get a diagram?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken Thanks for your comment. Here is a basic sequence diagram.https://www.screencast.com/t/OYJsKf7o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on diagram above, sending the JSON data from client to backend is duplicative. That information is already public and well-known (it's published on the blockchain).

Instead, the request from client to backend should simply be like "tell me about token 15". And the server should know everything everything about token 15 at that time.

Comment: Yeah, I know. All data is public now. So I should use etherscan API on backend?

Comment: I would use a direct node provider like Infura. But yes, Etherscan API is cool too.